# how to assign selected value from dropdown and assigns to records?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a dropdown in webgrid and i want to set default value for it as selected by user.i am assigning list to viewdata for dropdown selected value,which is working fine,but on adding multiple records ,it takes the last records selected value from dropdown and assigns to all records?any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are adding multiple records in the grid and each record has a dropdown whos value you need.. For this you will need to a do a little bit client side coding to have a row vs selected value pairs stored and then assign them to respective rows.